# Convert amount to gas value

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

What I want to achieve is to create a UI(e-Commerce user interface) to allow the user to enter the amount.In this case, the amount would be in USD; from the back-end, it will calculate and convert the USD amount to the corresponding gas value then send it to the Smart Contract. Has anyone experienced that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying you want your users to enter a budget (in USD) and convert that to a gas limit based on some predetermined gas price?

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Yes. For example, an online booking system, a user would enter a price.

Comment: It's a bit of an odd question (or I'm not understanding something), but there are plenty of APIs that will convert USD to ETH (CryptoCompare, Coinbase, just to name a couple). From there, you can set the gas price (or use `web3.eth.getGasPrice` to get the latest median) and compute what your gas limit is. But, the gas consumed is going to depend on what the contract is doing.

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Sorry for the confusion, and appreciate your answer. I will give a try on those APIs, would you mind if you have any example code? Many Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have anything handy at the moment. But, I'll be happy to answer questions if end up blocked by anything as you go through it. And I may be available for hire ;)

Comment: @AdamKipnis - Sounds a good idea.BTW, I found a website called GDAX; I am going to try it out. Wish me luck:). Would you mind to share with me your personal email?